# Derivative of $x-\sqrt { x } $

Tags: calculus

Compute $f'(x)$ using the limit definition

$$f(x)=x-\sqrt { x } $$

Steps I took:

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { x+h-\sqrt { x+h } -(x-\sqrt { x } ) }{ h }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { x+h-\sqrt { x+h } -x+\sqrt { x }  }{ h }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { h-\sqrt { x+h } +\sqrt { x }  }{ h }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \quad \frac { h }{ h } -\frac { \sqrt { x+h } +\sqrt { x }  }{ h }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \quad 1-\frac { \sqrt { x+h } +\sqrt { x }  }{ h }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \quad 1-(\frac { \sqrt { x+h } +\sqrt { x }  }{ h } \cdot (\frac { \sqrt { x+h } -\sqrt { x }  }{ \sqrt { x+h } -\sqrt { x }  } )) } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \quad 1-\frac { x+h-x }{ h(\sqrt { x+h } -\sqrt { x } ) }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \quad 1-\frac { h }{ h(\sqrt { x+h } -\sqrt { x } ) }  } \quad $$

$$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \quad 1-\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x+h } -\sqrt { x }  }  } \quad $$

So I got to this point and realize that as $h$ approaches zero and gets cancelled out the denominator would become zero. My answer looks similar to what the correct answer should look like except for the denominator. Where did I go wrong? I would like a hint. No direct answer. That won't help me.

Comment: you ought to put that $1$ outside the limit as soon as you found it. you made a mistake on the fourth line; it should read $f^\prime(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{h} - \frac{\sqrt {x + h} - \sqrt x}{h}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sign mistake in step $\#4$

It will be $$f'(x)=\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 } \frac { h }{ h } -\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}h$$

and
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}h=\frac{(x+h)-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)}$$

Comment: Is it like I am factoring out a $-1$?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Exactly